# Firebug - howto find currently executing method in JS (pause)

Tags: firebug

well... this might be obvious, but I cannot find it.

On this page: http://www.zxspectrum.net/ you can start game by clicking on it. Click executes js method: load(....).

I would like to find where this method is defined and set breakpoint on it.

How can I do that using Firebug futures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you type load into the console. It will say load is a function defined on line 9 which means it is a inline function. Then you go to scripts, find line 9 (or click on the load function in the console). Now you can set a breakpoint to line 9.

I am wonderung what you are trying to achieve, however. Don't copy scripts of people that dont want their scripts copied :-).

Comment: Just wanted to check, why there is no error message when java is not installed